# ASP.NET MVC: Passing Javascript value to Url.Action in Ajax Update

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC 4:

I am updating a div via ajax. The call to Url.Action needs to pass a value from the html DOM , in this case **$('#ClientID').val()** . I know the below is illegal but it shows my intent:

```
[script type="text/javascript"]
function UpdateTheDiv() {
    $.get('@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", 
        new {  
               parent = Model, 
               some_value_from_the_DOM=$('#SomeID').val() *** HERE IS THE PROBLEM ***
             })', 

        function (data) {
           $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
    }); 
}
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Url.Action` without parameters and pass the parameters in JavaScript.
Server side processing cannot access the client side DOM.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
        data: { 
                parent: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
                some_value_from_the_DOM: $('#SomeID').val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#detailsDiv").html(result); // update your div here
        },
        cache: false
    });
```